# RESTful-Authentication or Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authlogic, restful-authentication

I'm having trouble deciding between the two. They both seem like great plugins but I'd like to know which is easier to control.

What are your guy's experiences with these plugins? Which would you recommend?

Comment: what do you mean by "control"? I have used authlogic and could comment about my experience if I you could be more specific

Comment: well, for example; the way Authlogic sends a password reset email seems more complicated than the way RESTful-Authentication sends it,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would prefer Authlogic  than using  Restful authentication .

Is you use authologic with one big advantage over Restful authentication it comes as both gem/plugin  rather than a generator as in restful_authentication, it doesn't mess your application with lots of code .

Using Authlogic it's easy to understand  and it's cleaner compare to that of Restful authentication .

If your application requires email activation then use the act_as_state machine plugin with authologic.

"It's worth spending time creating  two applications using Authologic and Restful Authentication and select the best according to your needs :)"

Good luck!

Comment: Do you mean this plugin?: http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/tree/master
Could you provide a link to an example of how to use it for email activation?

Comment: Use can check this for email Activation  in Authlogic http://github.com/matthooks/authlogic-activation-tutorial/blob/b9bca1d5529754c1ea7361bfd92e228f25f369bc/01 , Good luck !